# Unit test case execution with local Impala connection

Tags: java, junit, testng, impala

I'm have an application which fetches data from Impala, does the process and generates final reports. written some  test cases to valiate the code in my local. During the test case execution  it connecting to remore impala server and fetching the data.

Due to the remote jdbc conection to impala  it is takeing long time to complete all my test cases.

I thought if impal can we setuped in local as jar or somhing  I will help in reducing the test case exectuion time.

Can some one suggest something to achive my objective.

Thinking somehting liek h2 datases which supports all impala  queries so I update laod data in execute

I tryied H2 database, postgress, mysql etc

Comment: Good to refer: https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/fe/src/test/java/org/apache/impala/service/JdbcTest.java, https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/fe/src/test/java/org/apache/impala/util/TestDisjointSet.java

Answer (score 0):

i highly suggest you to mock those impala calls. you can have a look at the mockito framework (https://site.mockito.org/) which offers ways of simple method mocking.

using this, you can just define in your test what the result in your impala query is and use this mocked data for your actual test.